# How to load data of string of date in csv to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, etl, load-data-infile

Here is a glimpse of my .csv file:

```
Name,Start Date,End Date,Budget
Class 1,1/1/2020,31/1/2020,"USD10,000.00"
Class 2,1/2/2020,28/2/2020,"USD14,000.00"
```

The date format in csv is `%e/%c/%Y`.

I am trying to load this data to a table `class`, here is what I have done:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/class.csv' 
INTO TABLE class
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(class_name, @start_date, @end_date, @budget)
SET start_date = REPLACE(@start_date, '/', '-'),
end_date = REPLACE(@start_date, '/', '-'),
budget = REPLACE(@budget, 'USD', ''),
budget = REPLACE(@budget, ',', '');
```

But it returns

> ```
> Error Code: 1292. 
> Incorrect date value: '1-1-2021' for column 'start_date' at row 1
> ```

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to use **[`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)** function such as

```sql
SET start_date = STR_TO_DATE(@start_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

as `start_date` is a **DATE** type column, but not an ordinary string. Presumably, the same logic should work also for`end_date`.